# rails select method and scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

On my user model I have these scope method

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :active, where(:deactivated => false)  
 end
```

I am using Amistad gem for handling friendships between users,when I want to fetch all active users I use select method.

```
   @user =User.find(params[:id])
   @friend =user.friends.select { |friend| friend.deactivated == false }
```

And it works great but with many and many queries on my postgreSql database ,on my console when I use:

```
   User.active
```

It gives me the right value,but when I use.

```
User.first.friends.active
```

It gives me.

```
  NoMethodError: undefined method `active' for #<Array:0x5eefa68>
```

Do you have any other solution for that I need to have less database queries ?.

Comment: It seems so and when I am using select method I got load of queries on my database

Comment: It doesn't make sense, #friends should return a Relation : https://github.com/raw1z/amistad/blob/master/lib/amistad/active_record_friend_model.rb#L97

Comment: I am using version 0.7.5 and these is #friends (https://github.com/raw1z/amistad/blob/v0.7.5/lib/amistad/active_record/friend_model.rb#L68)

Comment: As you see the + operation (in 0.7) will trigger the sql call on the db and the result will be an array. Upgrade to the last version : it will return an AR::Relation so you can then chain more scopes on it

Comment: I noticed that ..but migration to last version needs some modifications and I wanted to override that but I will update my gem to the last one ,thanks for help